# to_hash and strong_parameters for Rails 5.1 with an array of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I have the following params declaration:

```
   def line_item_params
     params.require(:line_items).map do |p|
       ActionController::Parameters.new(p.to_hash).permit(:quantity, :price, :menu_item_id)
     end
    end
```

but get the following error:

> Method to_hash is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1, as
>   `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from hash. Using
>   this deprecated behavior exposes potential security problems. If you
>   continue to use this method you may be creating a security
>   vulnerability in your app that can be exploited. Instead, consider
>   using one of these documented methods which are not deprecated:
>   http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

I am just posting an array of items. How should this be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def line_item_params
  # just to raise ActionController::ParameterMissing if key is missing
  params.require(:line_items) 
  # this is the actual whitelist
  params.permit(line_items: [:quantity, :price, :menu_item_id])
end
```

You can whitelist an array of objects by passing a hash option to `.permit` with an array containing the keys to whitelist for the nested objects.